# change SAS encoding to utf-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sas, sas-studio

I am struggling greatly with changing my SAS session to utf-8.

I have tried changing the cfg file - sasv9.cfg; however, I am told that access is denied

I have tried using the encoding option; however, it says I must apply this on start-up, I tried restarting SAS and entering it then, still no luck.

I have tried the locale function; however, it returns an invalid command warning.

I am pretty stuck here. I am using SAS base9.4 and I have tried to follow multiple different threads but cannot find a solution.

Comment: If the problem is editing the .cfg-file and you have administrator rights on your computer: try to copy the file to somewhere on your PC where you have writing rights (e.g. Desktop). Then edit the file, save and then paste it back into the program files folder.

Comment: Looks like I don't have administrator rights

Comment: Is the "access denied" error from your OS or from the product? What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm running windows and I don't have admin rights

Comment: Are you sure that you don't already have a command to start SAS with UTF-8 support? When my company installed SAS it created multiple commands (icons) in the start menu. Including  "SAS 9.4 (English)" and "SAS 9.4 (Unicode)".

Comment: amazing , just found SAS with Unicode support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the sasv9.cfg file from the location you do not have write access to a place you do (i.e. your Documents folder).  Change the encoding in there.

Start SAS on the command line with `-CONFIG "C:\path\to\cfg\sasv9.cfg"`

That should force SAS to start the session with the new config file and the specified encoding.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm working on a given laptop from the university and do not have admin rights

Comment: I changed the file and it didn't seem to work, the above comment should hopefully work